# How create an object from generic type class

Tags: java, generics

[image]This is a class, which I need to have an object from it to call its method.

```
public abstract class FileInputFormat<K, V> extends InputFormat<K, V> {

    // ...

    protected long computeSplitSize(long blockSize, long minSize,
                                  long maxSize) {
        return Math.max(minSize, Math.min(maxSize, blockSize));
    }

    // ...

}
```

I tried this:

```
FileInputFormat<K, V> test = new FileInputFormat<K, V>();
```

but it shows errors.

What should I do?

Comment: This question should not in hadoop tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to instantiate an object of a **generic** class, so you have to provide some **concrete** types in place of `K` and `V`, for example:

```
FileInputFormat<Integer, String> test=new FileInputFormat<Integer, String>();
```

Comment: how can I find its type?,http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java

Comment: It depends on your use case.

Comment: I just need to use its method, I use <string,integer>, but it shows an error .I added a picture to the question.

Comment: This is beacuse `FileInputFormat` is an abstract class, you need to provide constructor of a conrete one.

Comment: it that code ,why it create public class AirlineInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> ?I could not understand the meaning of it.

Comment: Do you understand the `abstract` keyword?

Comment: I know, It means it has no implementation.in your example why it doesn't write public class AirlineInputFormat extends RecordReader<Text, Text> ?why it creates   AirlineInputFormatClass  ?

Comment: This was just an example implementation (it's not mine).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of generics,you need to replace `K,V` with some class names.

In your case,it may be

```
FileInputFormat<Integer, String> test=new FileInputFormat<Integer, String>();


OR



FileInputFormat<String,Integer> test=new FileInputFormat<String,Integer>();
```

Comment: sorry, do you the answer of these question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341738/merge-time-and-reduce-time-are-0